# How to see who is visiting your site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a website built on ruby on rails currently hosted by heroku. I would like to know if their is a way I could see how many visitors I am getting. I also have a domain bought through godaddy.

Comment: Not sure if this is on topic, but I'd strongly recommend New Relic for this and other useful metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Thomas mentioned New Relic is a great way to see how many requests you are getting. I'm not sure if you can count "visits" (by IP?) using New Relic. However, Heroku currently offers 2 free levels of service so you can try it and see.

If you want to do it manually, you can save each request to the database and create a view to see the data. You could do this by using a before filter on the Application Controller. The big question is, **What is a visit?**

Probably the best way is to integrate Google Analytics, which is also free. Add the GA code to the layout.

Another way is to use a gem, but I doubt there would be an advantage to Google Analytics.